# NDSolve not solving my equations

Tags: differential-equations

I'm trying to evaluate a fairly simple equation but the code I've written simply prints the equation as output. Originally there was a typo in the summation code but that seems to be fixed, anyone seen this before:

```
Clear["Global`*"]
Clear[Derivative]
parameters = {mi -> 0.1, mj -> 0.1};
x = 1
u = wu
wu = wi + wj
wi = ((x) - xi) mi + 1
wj = ((x) - xj) mj + 1
oi = Sum [xj*wj, {wj, 1, u}]
oj = Sum [xi*wi, {wi, 1, u}]
Frequency = 
 NDSolve[{xi[t] = xi (wi - oi), xj[t] = xj (wj - oj), xi[0] == 8000, 
    xj[0] == 20000} /. parameters, {xi, xj}, {t, 0, 10000}]
{Plot[xA[t] /. Frequency, {t, 0, 10000}, PlotRange -> All],
 Plot[xB[t] /. Frequency, {t, 0, 10000}, PlotRange -> All]}
```

Comment: Welcome to MSE. I do not see any derivatives in the code?

Comment: The first argument to `NDSolve` does not contain equations. Even after you change the `=` to `==` you are using `xi` and `xj` as both functions (with `[t]`) and as variables (without `[t]`). There are no derivatives in the "differential equations". You cannot plot until you get `Frequency` producing a useable output.

Comment: I tried fixing it so that the same names were not used for variables and functions but that didn't solve the problem

Comment: Please edit your post with the latest version of the code. Did you add the derivatives?

Comment: Edited. The equation I have been using for vector plots has been dxi/t = xi(wi-oi). wi depends completely on the numerical value of xi which in turn alters wi over time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are really trying to solve differential equations, the following is my best guess to what you really want. At least, the following code has the merit of providing solutions albeit rather strange ones.

```
parameters = {mi -> 1/10, mj -> 01/10};
x = 1;
wi = (x - xi[t]) mi + 1;
wj = (x - xj[t]) mj + 1;
oi = Sum[w xj[t] , {w, wi + wj}];
oj = Sum[w xi[t], {w, wi + wj}];

Frequency =
 NDSolve[
   {xi'[t] == xi[t] (wi - oi), xj'[t] == xj[t] (wj - oj),
    xi[0] == 8000, xj[0] == 20000} /. parameters,
   {xi, xj}, {t, 0, .04},
   WorkingPrecision -> 30];

Plot[Evaluate[{xi[t], xj[t]} /. Frequency], {t, 0, .04},
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Dashed, Thickness[.007]],
  PlotLegends -> {xi[t], xj[t]},
  PlotRange -> {0, 20000}]
```

[image: plot1]

Notice that this plot only goes from o to 0.004 secs, not to 10000 secs you indicated. But the curves decay so quickly that is no reason to plot out even 1 sec. This behavior is produced by the initial conditions. The equations behave better if other initial conditions are assumed. For example:

```
Frequency =
 NDSolve[
   {xi'[t] == xi[t] (wi - oi), xj'[t] == xj[t] (wj - oj),
    xi[0] == 8, xj[0] == 20} /. parameters,
   {xi, xj}, {t, 0, 5}];

Plot[Evaluate[{xi[t], xj[t]} /. Frequency], {t, 0, 4},
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Dashed, Thickness[.007]],
  PlotLegends -> {xi[t], xj[t]},
  PlotRange -> {0, 20}]
```

[image: plot2]

Now I'm not implying that your initial conditions are bad, just that they are incompatible with the mathematica model expressed by your equations as rewritten by me. But I do conclude that something must change. Either the mathematical model, the initial conditions or both.

Comment: Thanks for this! We had wondered about the model but since the code wouldn't run at all it was difficult to say for sure that this was the problem.